# Make biblatex skip author for a specific citation, keep it in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to discard the `author` field of a biblatex entry in a specific `\cite` command (just as if it had no author at all), but still have it listed in the biliography.

I need this because the figures are my original works, and repeating my name in the citations themselves is akward. So basically:

```
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=300px]{image.jpg}
  \caption{\cite[]{the-biblatex-entry}} % *shouldn't* produce my name, only title, date, etc...
\end{figure}

\printbibliography % *should* produce my name, along with title, date, etc...
```

I'm ok with using some other command other than `\cite`. I'd really like to have a `\citenoauthor` command if I only knew how to make it.

EDIT: here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{somebook,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} %backend tells biblatex what you will be using to process the bibliography file
\bibliography{example}

\begin{document}
\cite{somebook} % I'd like this to not include the author, only the other fields
\printbibliography % All the fields, please
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\AtNextCitekey{\clearname{labelname}}\cite{the-biblatex-entry}`? Hard to say without a compilable (but minimal, please!) example for people to examine. Also: `biblatex-chicago` had (and still has, I'd guess) the commands `\headlesscite` and `\headlessfullcite`, which you could use for inspiration.

Comment: Added a MWE. How can I use those commands "for inspiration"?

Comment: Forgot to add that your `\AtNextCitekey` idea didn't work. It produces no effect.

Comment: `\AtNextCitekey{\clearname{author}}` for BibTeX (hence need for MWE; otherwise we can only guess). By 'inspiration', I meant you could adapt them to your own use. (Obviously, prior to the MWE, no one else could be certain how they could be adapted or, indeed, whether a better solution was available.)

Comment: I see. It does work, but not inside `\caption` :-( EDIT: Holdon, it does work, never mind. There's something fishy

Comment: The `caption` and `subcaption` packages break the technique, for some reason. But I don't need them, I think. So I guess it works. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `\protect` inside `\caption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\caption` problem can be fixed with a judicious use of `\protect` or you can define your own 'robust' command with `etoolbox`'s `\newrobustcmd` (`biblatex` requires and loads `etoolbox` by default). That is:

```
\caption{%
  \AtNextCitekey{\protect\clearname{author}}%
  \cite{somebook}}
```

or:

```
\newrobustcmd{\hlcite}[1]{%
  \AtNextCitekey{\clearname{author}}%
  \cite{#1}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{somebook,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{example}% <-- deprecated
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\usepackage{caption}

\newrobustcmd{\hlcite}[1]{%
  \AtNextCitekey{\clearname{author}}%
  \cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}
  \caption{%
    \AtNextCitekey{\protect\clearname{author}}%
    \cite{somebook}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}
  \caption{\hlcite{somebook}}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it is probably nicer to define `\hlcite` via `\DeclareCiteCommand`, because then the optional arguments will still work properly.

Comment: @moewe -- Yes, absolutely.  The point of it was more to showcase `\newrobustcmd` in the context of `\caption`'s moving argument as compared to `\protect`.